# Changing config files with awk/sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have two almost identical config files in two different directories

```
## file1.conf ##
tunnel:
    enable: true
    interval: 20
    public: false

loop:
    enable: false
    interval: 20
    public: false

link:
    enable: true
    interval: 20
    public: false

## file2.conf ##
tunnel:
    enable: true
    interval: 20
    public: false

loop:
    interval: 20
    enable: false
    public: false

link:
    enable: true
    interval: 20
    public: false
```

Now I want to change **enable: false** to **enable: true** but only for the **loop** section in both files. How can I do this using just one set of commands for both files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with an inplace edit using `sed -i`.

```
sed -i '/^loop:/,/^$/ { s/enable:.*$/enable: true/ }' file1.conf file2.conf
```

The command breaks down into two main parts:

```
/^loop:/,/^$/ { .... }
```

This means we limit the stuff inside the `{...}` to the section that begins with `loop:` and ends with a blank line.

Inside that we have

```
s/enable:.*$/enable: true/
```

Which simply ensures the `enable:` line is set to true.

The result is that we rewrite `file1.conf` and `file2.conf` so that the section beginning `loop:` and ending with a blank line has any `enable` line rewritten to `enable: true`

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to parse full block

```
sed -i '/loop/{:a;n;/enable/s/false/true/;Ta;}' file1.conf file2.conf
```